# Where can I learn more about the Galois connection induced by a graph on its own powerset?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, relations, infinitary-combinatorics

Given a binary relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$, we get an antitone Galois connection $(F,U) : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ in the usual way:

- The function $U : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is given by $U(A) = \{y ∈ Y \,|\, \forall a \in A, (a,y) \in R\}.$
- The function $F : \mathcal{P}(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ is given by $F(B) = \{x ∈ X \,|\, \forall b \in B, (b,x) \in R^\dagger\}.$

($R^\dagger$ denotes the converse of $R$.)

I'm interested in a special case of this. Assume that $X$ equals $Y,$ and that $R$ is a symmetric relation. That is, $R=R^\dagger$. Then $U$ equals $F,$ so lets write $C$ for either/both of $U,F$. In this case, let us say that $C$ is the *induced connection* of $R.$

We can say it a little differently. By *graph*, let us mean a set (not necessarily finite) equipped with a symmetric binary relation (not necessarily reflexive or irreflexive). Then to every graph $(X,R)$, there is an induced connection $C : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$.

> **Question.** Where can I learn more about the Galois connection induced by a graph on its own powerset?

Here's a couple of everyday examples.

**Example 0.** To every every inner product space $H$, we can assign a relation $R \subseteq H \times H$ defined by asserting that $(x,y) \in R$ iff $\langle x,y\rangle = 0.$ So the previous discussion applies. The induced connection of $R$ is the function $\mathcal{P}(H) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(H)$ that maps every $A \subseteq H$ to its [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) $A^\perp \subseteq H$. This particular connection has the interesting property that $A \cap A^\perp = \{0\}$.

**Example 1.** To every group $G,$ there is a relation $R \subseteq G \times G$ defined by asserting that $(x,y) \in R$ iff $x$ commutes with $y$. Then $R$ is symmetric. The induced connection of $R$ is the function $C : \mathcal{P}(G) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(G)$ that maps every $A \subseteq G$ to its [centralizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer#Definitions) $C(A) \subseteq X$. Note in this case that $A \cap C(A)$ needn't equal $\{1\}$, in contrast to the previous example. Anyway, with a bit of thought, this example can be generalized so that $X$ is allowed to be an arbitrary [abstract clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28algebra%29), or equivalently a [Lawvere theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory). This is the case of main interest for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the paper "A Primer on Galois Connections" by Erné et al. (see the preprint [here](http://www.math.ksu.edu/~strecker/primer.ps)), where an antitone Galois connection from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ is called a *polarity*. You will find therein many examples and references, including the link with *formal concept analysis*. However it does not deal specifically with the case where $R$ is symmetric.